# Is it possible for my school to see the apps that I use?

Tags: web-browser, wifi

So I've seen that they can see stuff if you search it on Google, Bing, etc., but can they see the apps on my phone like Snapchat, Instagram, etc.? If so, can they see me using them?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: yes. Because the apps generate traffic, for example the Instagram app will connect to Instagram servers, the school could monitor this. Whether they can legally do this depends on the country and some other specifics, in many countries they need to at least warn you before they are allowed to monitor your traffic on an individual level. (Not that they expect fourteen year olds to sue them.)

They should not be able to see what you search for online. You mention Google and Bing specifically. Unless your phone is backdoored with something from school (such as a Certificate Authority or special software), or if they cut some deal with Google and Bing (extremely unlikely), they cannot see that. Any website with https should be secured from your devices until the server that the domain belongs to. But again, if they installed software or a Certificate Authority, they can intercept it regardless. (In that case, your device is no longer really yours.)

You can always use mobile data to avoid them from seeing it. They would need to intercept your mobile data and crack the connection (which is probably illegal in most countries), which I doubt your school is able to do.

Any app, or features with in an app, that does not use a network connection (i.e. if it functions with WiFi and mobile data turned off), it should not be visible to them.

Comment: Using a VPN would also be a good obfuscation technique.

Comment: @securityOrange not necessarily.  The fact that they are connected to a VPN tends to be very obvious in network traffic.  Of course, the VPN will hide all your activities from the school, but what it doesn't hide is the fact that you're connected to a VPN.  In some cases that can make you stick out and become a target for more detailed followup.  Granted, we're talking about a school here and not an authoritarian dictatorship (well, depends on the school), but a VPN definitely isn't a simple panacea.  There are work places where use of a VPN is a fire-able offense.

Comment: If they can see Google and Bing traffic, as OP claims, then they must have some sort of backdoor and a VPN is not going to help either.

Comment: @ConorMancone That’s a very good point! I was only thinking of the technical side there and didn’t consider the social/observability element. Good call out!

Answer (score 1):

They more likely identify  the app that you are using, but not exactly what you are doing.

Even if the app or the website use https (they likely do) your school will still be able to identify the source (you) and the destination (the servers app, with what they will be able to know that you are using Instagram or whatever ) of a communication.

You can reasonably assume that your school does not have the ressource to sees the communication itself. They probably  just want to see if someone goes to some dangerous or illegal websites.